# How to calculate Standard Deviation in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter, how to calculate Standard deviation?

E.g.:

```
Samples: 1000
Average: 305
```

Then how to calculate Std.Dev?

Answer (score 3):

Add a Listener of type "Summary Report".  It calculates Standard Deviation for you and includes it as a column of the table.